# C++ program ends before user input

Tags: c++, function

For my C++ homework, I am supposed to use one function to read to integers, use another one to add them and the last one to print out the sum. I am doing the first function and my program ends before allowing for input

I have tried using cin: clear and nothing changed I have tried removing the return and got an error.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int A;
int B;
int X;

//void Input();

int main()
{
    int Input(int A, int B);
    return 0;
}

int Input(int A, int B)
{
    cin >> A;
    cin >> B;
    return 0;
}
```

I expected it to blink telling the user to enter input because I can not use input messages but it runs then ends without letting me enter input

Comment: Why is your post & code formatted like this? It's very hard to read. Why don't you fix it?

Comment: that's how it came out when I was finished asking it

Comment: Then you were not finishing asking it.

Answer (score 4):

```
int Input(int A, int B);
```

This is a declaration. It is not a call.

Furthermore there does not appear to be any reason for `Input` to take any `int` parameters.

Turn to the page in your C++ book about using functions.